# Remove Tamil Fonts from Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, language-support

I have installed Ubuntu using wubi from windows. But somehow Tamil fonts came up. Tamil fonts are appearing in menu bar. Files and folders are even named in Tamil.

How can I remove Tamil language and make US English the default?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a terminal window and copy and paste the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-arabeyes ttf-arphic-ukai ttf-arphic-uming ttf-baekmuk ttf-bengali-fonts ttf-devanagari-fonts ttf-gentium ttf-gujarati-fonts ttf-indic-fonts ttf-kacst ttf-kacst-one ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-khmeros-core ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-lao ttf-malayalam-fonts ttf-mgopen ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-punjabi-fonts ttf-takao-pgothic ttf-vlgothic ttf-tamil-fonts ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-thai-tlwg ttf-unfonts-core ttf-indic-fonts-core ttf-wqy-zenhei
   ```
2. Then copy and paste:

   ```
   aptitude search ~i| grep font
   ```
3. remove any other remaining fonts you don't want BUT:

DO NOT REMOVE:

```
Any xfonts or xfont utilities
x-tccidfont-conf
ttf-opensymbol
ttf-dejavu
anything that starts with lib
fontconfig
defoma
anything that starts with console
gsfonts
```

Hope you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

I actually think that your problem is not due to the presence to Tamil fonts in your system but due to Tamil being the default language on your system. To make English(US) as your default language, do the following:

- From the Dash Home, open Language Support.
- In the 'Language' tab, you will find a list called `Language for menus and windows`.
- Choose `English (United States)` and click `Apply system-wide` button. The change will take effect on the next log-in/boot.